# Io's method scope

Tags: metaprogramming, iolanguage

How does the Io's method scope work?
When I define:

```
method(x, x + 1)
```

what object does slot `x` belong to? I tried `self`, `call` and even `Object` without any luck?

For example in the REPL:

```
slotNames
```

is the same as

```
Lobby slotNames
```

in a method:

```
method(slotNames)
```

is the same as? What?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`x` is stored in the arguments list of the message not as slots.

You can access the arguments of the current message via

`m := method(x, y, call message arguments)`.